# How to hide/suppress and rename/alias fields when exporting to KML?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, kml, convert, attribute-table, editing

I have a feature class that needs to be exported to a KML file. I wonder if there is a way for me to export only some of the columns of the feature class's attribute table; some attributes are not needed in the KML file. Also, some of the column headings of the attribute table need to be edited to make them more understandable by a layperson. Is there a way of doing this when exporting to KML? Or, is there a way to make these edits in a KML file once it already exists? I'm exporting from ArcGIS 10.0, in case this helps.

Comment: I have not tested but if you hide unwanted fields and alias the name of others using layer properties (or ArcPy) then I would expect Layer To KML to respect those settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like PolyGeo said,

1. Open layer properties
2. Click the 'Fields' Tab
3. Make sure only the fields you want in your KMZ are checked
4. Give those fields an alias

When you run the layer to KML tool it will only export the headings you want.
An example can be seen [HERE](http://ideas.arcgis.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=087E00000004bwo&feoid=Body&refid=0EME0000000Tbr9)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I tried hiding some fields and aliasing others and it worked.